# Database design for Food Court Ordering Program which can update the availability

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, database-trigger

I'm planning to make a self-order(kiosk) food court program.

This is the architecture that I plan to build. (The database server is a local server, it's not on a cloud).

[image: Architecture]

Basically, I will have a local database server which runs MySQL server.
Every food stall has a computer which connects to the database server. Every food stall can update their menu and the availability. For example, every seller can mark which menu is out of stock (unavailable). Besides that, when there is an order the seller can be notified. When he has delivered the order he can update the order status as "Done".
There is more than one ordering machine which connects to the database server. Every buyer will insert their table number when he makes an order.

Here is my current database design.

```
Seller Table
Seller Username (Unique, Primary Key) | Seller Password | Name of the Stall

Menu Table
Menu ID (AutoIncrement, Primary Key) | Food Name | Price | Availability | Seller ID (Foreign Key) //Seller ID is used to indicate who sells the product

Order Table
Order ID (AutoIncrement, Primary Key) | Total Price | Table Number

Order Detail Table
Order ID (Foreign Key) | Food Name | Quantity | Table Number | Seller ID (Foreign Key) | Status //Status is used to determine whether the order has been delivered or not
```

**EDIT**

My questions are:

- Is the database design correct?
- How can I avoid the buyer to buy a product which is not available? For example, suddenly the seller change the availability of Burger. But the self-order machine has made the query so that Burger is shown on the self-order machine screen. Someone suggested that when buyer click order the machine have to check it the availability first, but how to do that (what is the query)?
- How to notify the seller when there is an order immediately? Do my apps have to make a query every minute to order detail table?

Comment: Apart from being way too broad, this isn't a Python nor PyQT question (fixed tags).

Comment: Sketch out the `SELECTs`, `INSERTs`, and `UPDATEs` that need to be applied.  In doing so, you will see flaws in the design, and/or we will have more to work with.

Comment: what kind of flaws? I think GMB's answer can handle my second question. But currently my problem how many seller apps can be notified when there is a new order.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of design, you should create more relationships between your tables. Do not duplicate information, instead use foreign keys that link to the table where information is stored.

Specifically : in the *Order Detail*, replace field *Food Name* with a foreign key to the *Menu ID* (from *Menu* table). To validate the product availability when an order is placed, you might use a **trigger** that uses that relationship, like :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER check_order_before_insert()
BEFORE INSERT ON order_detail FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT availability FROM menu WHERE menu_id = = NEW.menu_id) = 0
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot order : product not available';
    END IF;
END;
$$
```

Comment: wow wonderful, thanks for your help. Anyway is it okay to store all seller menu in one table? do I have to make a separate menu table for every seller?

Comment: you want a single `menu` table, with a foreign key that references the `seller` table

Comment: yes it's a good approach to store all seller menu in one table

Comment: btw, How to notify the seller when there is an order immediately?

Comment: you can use a trigger as well, on `order` for example

Comment: okay, I got it.  but how my apps communicate with order detail? Do I have to make a query every minute? I mean how to refresh the seller screen